# SQL insert into select with COUNT(*) AS CountOf

Tags: mysql

I removed all duplicates from a table. I want to insert all the rows that remain into the same table with a hardcoded 'term_taxonomy_id' value.

I used the following query to remove all duplicate 'object_id' values ->

```
SELECT object_id, 
       term_taxonomy_id, 
       Count(*) AS CountOf 
FROM   wp_term_relationships 
WHERE  term_taxonomy_id = 1043 
        OR term_taxonomy_id = 1195 
GROUP  BY object_id 
HAVING Count(*) > 1;
```

Now I want to insert those 'object_id' values to the same table with a hardcoded 'term_taxonomy_id' ->

```
INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships 
            (object_id, 
             term_taxonomy_id) 
SELECT object_id, 
       1224, 
       Count(*) AS CountOf 
FROM   wp_term_relationships 
WHERE  term_taxonomy_id = 1043 
        OR term_taxonomy_id = 1195 
GROUP  BY object_id 
HAVING Count(*) > 1;
```

I tried the above but I got the following error -> #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1. To me, it looks like count doesn't have a  column to save its value but I don't want to save this. Does anyone know how I can use the above select query to insert it into the same table again with a hardcoded term_taxonomy_id?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - just remove `Count(*) AS CountOf` column from the select list

```
INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships 
            (object_id, 
             term_taxonomy_id) 
SELECT object_id, 
       1224
FROM   wp_term_relationships 
WHERE  term_taxonomy_id in (1043,1195) 
GROUP  BY object_id 
HAVING Count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that the number of columns returned by your query does not match the number of columns that you are declaring for insert.

Your query returns 3 columns, while you are declaring 2 columns for insert.

It looks like you would just need to remove column `CounfOf` from the columns returned by your query, so :

```
INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships(object_id, term_taxonomy_id) 
SELECT object_id, 1224
FROM  wp_term_relationships 
WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 1043 OR term_taxonomy_id = 1195 
GROUP BY object_id 
HAVING Count(*) > 1;
```

Another option is to add one more column to the list of columns for insert.

```
INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships(object_id, term_taxonomy_id, count_of) 
SELECT object_id, 1224, Count(*)
FROM  wp_term_relationships 
WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 1043 OR term_taxonomy_id = 1195 
GROUP BY object_id 
HAVING Count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need  the same number of column (and matching data types) between insert and select
so or you add  a column to the INTO clause

```
INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships 
            (object_id, 
             term_taxonomy_id,
             term_value) 
SELECT object_id, 
       1224, 
       Count(*) AS CountOf 
FROM   wp_term_relationships 
WHERE  term_taxonomy_id = 1043 
        OR term_taxonomy_id = 1195 
GROUP  BY object_id 
HAVING Count(*) > 1;
```

or you you remove a column from the select

```
INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships 
            (object_id, 
             term_taxonomy_id) 
SELECT object_id, 
       1224, 
FROM   wp_term_relationships 
WHERE  term_taxonomy_id = 1043 
        OR term_taxonomy_id = 1195 
GROUP  BY object_id 
HAVING Count(*) > 1;
```